# How to make it in one query

Tags: sql, select

I have  the following relational table schema

```
Customer(customer_id, customer_name, customer_city)
Branch(branch_id, branch_name, branch_city)
Account(account_id, balance, customer_id, branch_id)
```

Question name every customer who has accounts in branches at least two different cities. 
It is working for me the next query but only if I create a view first. Is there any other option to do it together?

My solution which works:

```
Create view Cust as select c.Customer_Name, c.customer_ID, b.branch_name, b.branch_city from Customer as c inner Join Account as a on c.customer_ID=a.customer_ID join Branch as b on b.branch_id=a.branch_id
SELECT * FROM Cust as c inner join Cust as c1 on c.CustomerID=c1.CustomerID and c.branch_city <> c1.branch_city
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using `exists` with an aggregate query

```
select c.*
from customer c
where exists (
    select 1
    from account a 
    inner join branch b on b.branch_id = a.branch_id
    where a.customer_id = c.customer_id
    group by c.customer_id
    having min(b.branch_city) <> max(b.branch_city)
)
```